# Multiple cronjobs possibly accessing log file at the same time

Tags: cron

As the title says: I have multiple cronjobs loading python scripts, that start at different times. The scripts do different things and thus take different amounts of time to finish. So it's pretty likely that they will overlap from time to time. During their runtime they write all their output into log file. The scripts (and its results) are completely independent from each other.

What happens if multiple scripts try to write to the same logfile at the same time?

If there is a problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: Easy, just let the script write on separate logfile and add a final cronjob which is a simple "cat" to merge all the log files into a single one. Is it possible for you doing this?

Comment: Yeah, that possible. So there is a problem with mutiple accesses at the same time? Is merging files the only solution to this problem?

Comment: No you can do it, but the output would be a mess. You'll end up with a log file with too many information from every script that access it jumping from row to row. Instead, IMHO, you would want to read a log file with separate paragraph of every script. Or at least this is how I manage my scripts when they write to a single unique log file. It's just easier to read

Comment: Ok, thanks for the description. Will use different files and merge them.